# Intel XDK + google services plugin + IOS = build fails

Tags: ios, cordova, intel-xdk

I had an issue with this Google maps plugin (https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/)

I use Intel XDK to build my apps, and I had no problem building Android versions with that plugin, but with IOS I get this error:

```
.../plugin.google.maps/Marker.m:376:3: error: use of undeclared identifier 'pluginResult'
```

My intel xdk addition is normal (I guess)

```
<intelxdk:plugin intelxdk:name="GoogleMaps" intelxdk:id="plugin.google.maps" intelxdk:value="https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin.git">
    <intelxdk:param intelxdk:name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" intelxdk:value="AIzaSyBnFeZRSurmAh..." />
    <intelxdk:param intelxdk:name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" intelxdk:value="AIzaSyCEfAzwqRlSaFdIK..." />
</intelxdk:plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I talked with the Plugin Developer sending my build log and he identified the bug, a new version is already published to anyone who had the same problem.